# jOOQ CommonTableExpression with SelectQuery

Tags: common-table-expression, jooq

We have a query with a common structure that we use under different circumstances (where clause is different)

So we have something like this

```
val baseQuery: SelectQuery<Record> = dsl
  .select(someFields)
  .from(someTable)
  .join(otherTable).on(joinClause)
  .query
```

In other places we then extend this query however needed.

```
baseQuery.apply {
  addConditions(conditionsA)
}.fetch()

baseQuery.apply {
  addConditions(conditionsB)
}.fetch()
```

So far so good. But now it would be cool if we could somehow use this base in combination with a CTE. Not sure how to do that though.

```
val someCTE: CommonTableExpression<*> = DSL.....

// dsl
//   .with(someCTE)
//   .selectQuery(baseQuery.apply {}) ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

baseQuery.apply {
  // addWith(someCTE) ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
  addSelect(someCTE.field(cteField))
  addJoin(someCTE, joinClause)
  addConditions(conditionsC)
}
```

Is there a way to do it? Perhaps other suggestions how to reuse the base query when using a CTE?

**Edit: Solution**

With the help of Lukas' answer I settled on this approach

```
fun dynamicQuery(
  context: SelectSelectStep<*> = dsl.select(),
  selects: List<Field<*>> = listOf(),
  joins: List<Pair<Table<*>, Condition>> = listOf(),
  conditions: List<Condition> = listOf()
): SelectQuery<Record>
```

So in normal customizations I can

```
dynamicQuery(
  conditions = conditionsA
).fetch()

dynamicQuery(
  conditions = conditionsB
).fetch()
```

It can be combined with a CTE

```
val someCTE: CommonTableExpression<*> = DSL.....
dynamicQuery(
  context = dsl.with(someCTE).select(),
  selects = listOf(someCTE.field(cteField)),
  joins = listOf(someCTE to joinClause),
  conditions = conditionsC
).fetch()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: You can't use CTEs with jOOQ 3.15's model API

#### Some background on the jOOQ model API vs DSL API distinction

The very old jOOQ 1.0 only had what is now called the "model API", a mutable, procedural API with setters (no getters), where you can manipulate dynamic SQL.

jOOQ 2.0 introduced the DSL API, which is what most people are using today. The fact that the DSL API mimicks the SQL language helps users discover jOOQ API much more easily. Everything is named exactly as expected. With the exception of a few quirks in the areas of CTE and derived tables, you can write jOOQ-SQL almost just like actual SQL.

The model API was not deprecated, but wrapped by the DSL API, and kept around:

- for backwards compatibility reasons
- because some people seemed to like the procedural approach

You can't do anything with the model API that you couldn't do with the DSL API as well, though a more functional programming style may be helpful when doing this with the DSL API. See: https://blog.jooq.org/2017/01/16/a-functional-programming-approach-to-dynamic-sql-with-jooq

#### The future of jOOQ

While the model API is still getting some new clauses support for `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` statements, there are some statements that are not available in a model API form. These include `MERGE`, `TRUNCATE`, all [DDL statements](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/ddl-statements/), all [procedural statements](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/procedural-statements/). And, the `WITH` clause.

The strategy is to eventually deprecate the model API, because the redundancy creates a lot of extra work that is better invested elsewhere. There are also subtle bugs when people call model API methods in unexpected order, i.e. an order that is not possible through the DSL API.

- In a first step, pretty soon, jOOQ will inverse the relationship between APIs: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11241. The model API will be the auxiliary wrapper of the DSL API for those who rely on it for backwards compatibility. It isn't unlikely that the model API will even be extracted into a separate compatibility module, to discourage its use in new code
- In a next step, with the dependencies inversed, the DSL API can finally become consistently immutable, which is what many users expect, and to their surprise, find lacking: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9047
- Eventually, the model API will be deprecated, and then dropped

You can still use it today, and the deprecation and removal will be done over a long period of time, so there's no hurry in getting off this API (as always with jOOQ). But in the context of your question, it's good to see that jOOQ will not invest in adding too many features to it, anymore. CTE support won't be added to the model API.

#### Workarounds

You can, of course, work around this limitation, because internally, the model API is CTE capable:

- You could use reflection to add new CTEs to the `SelectQuery` internal representation. I won't document how this works, here, because it's never a good idea to document these things :)
- You could start creating a query using the DSL API, and then extract the internal `SelectQuery` representation using `SelectFinalStep.getQuery()`, and continue working from there.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately there is no common interface on how to start a query between `WithStep` and `DSLContext`. When building my dynamic query I'm now starting with `SelectSelectStep`. So in normal cases I start the dynamic query with `dslContext.select()....dynamicQuery` and for the CTE case I start with `dslContext.with().select()....dynamicQuery`. It's a bit unfortunate having to add that empty `select()` would be cool if the  `select()` query start method could be on a common interface.

Comment: @RanilWijeyratne: I understand the limitation. I don't think that particular suggestion is possible currently. We'd have to extract an initial "step" for all statements, and let `DSLContext` extend all of those initial steps, which seems to be overkill just for this case. But there might be a better solution. We should accept empty collections or arrays for the `WITH` clause, and then just not generate any such clause. Unfortunately, it currently doesn't work: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11347. Will fix this right away.

Comment: @RanilWijeyratne: 3.14.7 got released with this fix